# How to sort a list view column having $ sign like amount?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, listviewitem

I am facing some problem in sorting. I have the following code from msd document it works for all field, but not for amount fields that start with character like **$** for example

```
     amount
      $1900
      $4444 
      $39
      $0
```

This code does not sort that column so what changes should i make so that it also sorts the amount having $ sign at start.

This is the code:

```
class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer {
private int col;
private SortOrder order;
public ListViewItemComparer() {
    col=0;
    order = SortOrder.Ascending;
}
public ListViewItemComparer(int column, SortOrder order) 
{
    col=column;
    this.order = order;
}
public int Compare(object x, object y) 
{
    int returnVal= -1;
    returnVal = String.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text,
                            ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text);
    // Determine whether the sort order is descending.
    if(order == SortOrder.Descending)
        // Invert the value returned by String.Compare.
        returnVal *= -1
    return returnVal;
 }
}
```

and I am calling that code in listview column click event as

```
    private void lvwUsers_ColumnClick(Object eventSender, ColumnClickEventArgs eventArgs)
    {


        if (lvwUsers.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
            lvwUsers.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
        else
            lvwUsers.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

        lvwUsers.Sort();

        this.lvwUsers.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(eventArgs.Column,
                                                          lvwUsers.Sorting);

      }
```

It works fine but not for amount having $ sign with them

So how to sort listview having amount column with $ sign?

Comment: First you should delete the $ from your list after that sort it and then add it to the result

Comment: Thats the problem with ListView: everything is string.  The issue is that "$9" will sort higher than "$100" because the character "9" is greater than "1".  The DataGridView would be a better choice

Comment: no can you please tell me any trick like i used to trim $ but it wont work i have to make that change in existing erp so i would not change listview to grid view it is generic and called in 100 forms

Comment: The problem is not the currency symbol - the problem is that strings are not numbers.  You need to use a Natural Sort

Comment: Use the `Tag` on the ListViewItem (or sub-item) to store the actual amount in the correct format (`decimal` perhaps). Sort on that. String sorting on numbers is bad.

Comment: WHY THIS MARK DOWN having valuable material for developers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a comparer. Why not just modify it to sort the way you want? Use Decimal.Parse to convert the strings to decimal values, then compare those instead. No need to modify your list data. It also self-adapts to different cultures.

If the data can contain something other than currency values, you may want to make this code a bit more resilient to handle whatever types of values you get.

```
    class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
    {
        private int col;
        private SortOrder order;
        public ListViewItemComparer()
        {
            col = 0;
            order = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        public ListViewItemComparer(int column, SortOrder order)
        {
            col = column;
            this.order = order;
        }
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            int returnVal = -1;
            decimal value1;
            Decimal.TryParse(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col].Text,
                             System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency,
                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
                             out value1);
            decimal value2;
            Decimal.TryParse(((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col].Text,
                             System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, 
                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
                             out value2);
            returnVal = Decimal.Compare(value1, value2);
            // Determine whether the sort order is descending.
            if (order == SortOrder.Descending)
                // Invert the value returned by String.Compare.
                returnVal *= -1;
            return returnVal;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Food for thought
This method is hard coded for dollar signs but, there could be a regular expression that detects the non numeric characters, stores them, and then you would inject them back into the strings at the end.

```
    private List<string> sortthelist(List<string> incomingList)
    {
        List<int> convertedlist = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < incomingList.Count; i++)
        {
            convertedlist.Add(int.Parse(incomingList[i].Replace("$", "")));//convert your strings into integers
        }

        convertedlist.Sort();//sort your integers
        incomingList.Clear();//clear the existing list
        foreach (int item in convertedlist)//fill it back up
        {
            incomingList.Add("$" + item.ToString());//add the dollar sign back into the string
        }

        return incomingList;//return the sorted list
    }
```

Comment: can you implement it in column click i clicked 4th column